# Adding Swing components to a LibGDX screen

Tags: java, swing, libgdx, screen, components

As opposed to most questions I have seen where people are trying to add a LibGDX canvas to a JFrame or similar, I am trying for the opposite.

I have been working on a LibGDX game that utilises a Swing level editor. Both the game and the editor work quite well, but an issue I am having is that whenever I click on "Editor" in my main menu (which is a LibGDX Screen derivative), it opens up a new JFrame, so that I have two windows. Ideally, I would like to have it so that my Editor extends Screen, and allow it to be pushed onto the GameStateManager stack.

The issue is I have no idea how I would go about adding an entire Swing canvas to a Screen or something similar so that it could be applied to the stack. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible (or it's a bloody mess wrought with issues which you'd be better off not wasting your time to solve), basically because `LibGDX` is making use of an AWT `Canvas` to provide a rendering surface for `LibGDX` to paint to, which is a separate paint process from Swing, which has it's own, inbuilt, painting process.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hmm... I was concerned something along these lines would be the case. Is there anything that you can suggest that would allow these things to merge, even if it isn't perfect? I was thinking that I do't even need to have a frame, and essentially make it so that the AWT update/rendering is what i running, and the LibGDX render and update methods could simply be empty functions. But if there are further issues with this...